# URL with added android variable and Glide

Tags: android, android-studio, android-glide

I am using the glide library for my images in my app creation. I am getting a problem when i try to add a variable string to the base URL i have placed inside the load feature of Glide. The image does not return and i have found that using the url with the plus and then the variable is the problem. How do you go about adding fixing this and getting it to load with Glide?

Here is what i have...

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Movie movie = list.get(position);


Glide.with(context)
    .load("https://mywebsite.com/images/" + movie.getImagename())
    .into(holder.artImage);

    holder.textTitle.setText(movie.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: yes if i just add the image name to the url rather than movie.getImagename it will load but i obviously can't do that as its getting multiple instances of a class

Comment: Share onBindViewHolder

Comment: Added OnBindViewHolder

Comment: Where are you getting the `context` from ? Is it `holder.artImage.getContext()`?

Comment: private Context context;

Comment: Where is it being initialized? Can you try changing it to `holder.artImage.getContext()`?

Comment: Just inside the public  class for the adapter

Comment: Adding getContext onto artImage throws a context error. The holder.artImage isnt the problem, its the url and adding the contents of movie.getImage() to it.

Comment: Can you please add a `listener` to `Glide` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079354/glide-onerror-callback) and tell us what the `error message` is ? I suspect that the image is loading, just not showing for you

Comment: use .dontAnimate()