# What's the view I should use in Glide.with() function

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-gridview

I'm developing an app and I want to display `ArrayList` in `GridView` for that I use an adapter the object includes 3 Strings.
number, hint, imageURL

I want to put each object in the `GridView` I successfully put the number and hint because it's just `setText` but with the `ImageURL`, I want to display `Image` in an `ImageView` but I can't figure out why my program doesn't work

I'm using `Glide.with(context).load(roadSign.getImageURL()).into(SIGN_IMAGE_VIEW);`

The function is in the Adapter class

I don't think the problem is in the function I think something is wrong with the `Image` so I'm adding everything related

https://www.codepile.net/pile/Qe1XpjG9

If you need any more information please comment below

Comment: You can add a listener to glide to catch any error exception and log it: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51965942/2711811

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Glide takes context in Glide.with() so try this:

```
Glide.with(context).load(roadSign.getImageURL()).into(SIGN_IMAGE_VIEW);
```

Comment: I have tried it but the result is that the image is not appears

Comment: Add your adapter's full code to your question please.

Comment: Just added the adapter

Comment: have you tried clean and rebuild the project?  Sometimes the cache makes it unable to get the references @Yaniv

Comment: Are you showing the data in a RecyclerView? ListView? or what?

Comment: I'm showing the data in GridView I will try to rebuild now

Comment: rebuild and clean was not helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
Glide.with(view).load(roadSign.getImageURL()).into(SIGN_IMAGE_VIEW);
```

Try to do this and if the view doesn't work try to add convertview object....coz glide takes view object now

```
  @NonNull
  public static RequestManager with(@NonNull View view) {
    return getRetriever(view.getContext()).get(view);
  }
```

Comment: The first function doesn't woks Can you explain me exactly what to do?

Comment: Have you tried to add the convertView object, which you used as parameter in the method argument?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the image URL was HTTP and not HTTPs because I use android 8 and apparently it's not acceptable

Answer (score 0):

i dont know imageurl but as you answered it is the `http` permission problem. you should add the following for http request in

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
           //....
           />
```

and always use the listener to find the exception error

```
  Glide.with(context)
 .load(roadSign.getImageURL())
  .listener(new RequestListener() {
   @Override
   boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model,    
     Log.e(TAG, "Load failed", e);
     return false; // Allow calling onLoadFailed on the Target.
   }

   @Override
   boolean onResourceReady(R resource, Object model, Target<R> target,
       DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
     // Log successes here or use DataSource to keep track of cache hits and misses.
     return false;
   }
})
.into(imageView);
```